# Why are my integration tests not executed?

Tags: integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I use surefire and failsafe to execute unit tests respectively, integration tests. All tests reside in the folder `src/test/java`. So far I have one integration test class `TaskAdditionIT.java` whose test methods (annotated with @Test) are never executed while all unit tests are run. This is an excerpt of my pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>                                          
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>   
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>                     
</plugin>                                         
<plugin>                                          
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>   
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>                     
    <configuration>                               
        <executions>                              
            <execution>                           
                <goals>                           
                    <goal>integration-test</goal> 
                    <goal>verify</goal>           
                </goals>                          
            </execution>                          
        </executions>                             
    </configuration>                              
</plugin>
```

I use the maven goal `verify` to run the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Do not nest `executions` inside `configuration`:

```xml
<plugin>                                          
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>   
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>                              
    <executions>                              
        <execution>                           
            <goals>                           
                <goal>integration-test</goal> 
                <goal>verify</goal>           
            </goals>                          
        </execution>                          
    </executions>                              
</plugin>
```